# Zurb Foundation 4 topbar menu not expanding in Chrome or Safari

Tags: zurb-foundation

Using Rails with Zurb Foundation 4, the menu link that shows up when the window is too narrow doesn't work. It's supposed to expand to the menu options, but nothing happens when clicking on it, no errors in the console either. On Firefox it works perfect. Unfortunately I only really care about this in Chrome or Safari for mobile browsers!

This is the site:
http://www.mustangvball.com/

Comment: works for me on chrome (desktop, not mobile)

Comment: @DarrenKopp - hmm, doesn't work for me on Chrome. I'm on a mac. I've always had weird issues like this with Foundation's topbar.

Comment: Seeing that this post is a month old and the site appears to be working on mobile browsers again, I'm assuming that you've fixed it

Comment: @Dylan - yes we fixed it I think by changing the font of one of the items in the top bar.. I don't remember exactly.